# async OR step in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm not able to get my asynchronous code working with node.js

Trying both async and step libraries -- the code only returns the first function (doesn't seem to go through the rest). What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

```
var step = require('step');
step(
function f1(){
        console.log('test1');
},
function f2(){
        console.log('test2');
},
function finalize(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err);return;}
    console.log('done with no problem');
  }
);
```

or THIS:

```
var async = require('async');
async.series([
function f1(){
        console.log('test1');
},
function f2(){
        console.log('test2');
},
function finalize(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err);return;}
    console.log('done with no problem');
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step.js is expecting callbacks for each step.  Also the function that is using Step should callback with the result and not return it.

So let's say you have:

```
function pullData(id, callback){
  dataSource.retrieve(id, function(err, data){
    if(err) callback(err);
    else callback(data);
  });
}
```

Using Step would work like:

```
var step = require('step');

function getDataFromTwoSources(callback){
  var data1,
    data2;
  step(
    function pullData1(){
      console.log('test1');
      pullData(1, this);
    },
    function pullData2(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      data1 = data;
      console.log('test2');
      pullData(2, this);
    },
    function finalize(err, data) {
      if(err)
        callback(err);
      else {
        data2 = data;
        var finalList = [data1, data2];
        console.log('done with no problem');
        callback(null, finalList);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

This would get it to proceed through the steps.

Note that I personally prefer async for two reasons:

- Step catches all thrown errors and does a callback with them; this changes the behavior of the application, when these libraries should just be cleaning up the look of the code.
- Async has much better combination options and looks cleaner

Comment: is doSomething() the callback function in each of the functions, i.e. f1 and f2?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding callbacks very well; trying to get at 2 separate functions that retrieve results from a db into an array, and then the second function that processes the array. i figured having them sequential is the right way to do it (or nested), but not sure what the callbacks structure should be. sorry not more clear on this :(

Comment: what does "callback(null, {a : '5'});" do specifically?

Comment: with node.js, every callback should have two arguments: the first is the error, and the second is the data that is passed back.  So "callback(null, {a : '5'});" is essentially saying there was no error, and you are returning data - {a : '5'}.  I will flush out the examples more.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak to `async`, but for that your anonymous functions in the array you pass to `async.series` must call the `callback` parameter that is passed into those functions when the function is done with its processing.  As in:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        console.log('test1');
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('test2');
        callback();
    }
]);
```

Comment: I tested this, and of course it worked. I guess the callback is required. what's the point of the callback though when there's nothing really to do except execute the code serially?

Comment: Because typically your `async.series` function has an asynchronous aspect to it, and you'll only call the callback when that's completed (potentially long after the function itself has returned).

Comment: It gets passed into the top-level callback that you provide as the second parameter to `async.series`.  See the [docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#series).